# How to create metric in MAQL

Tags: gooddata

I have a measure called "TimeSpent", which is time that the user spends in seconds on a certain page. I have an attribute called "Domain" which is the site the user visited, and I have the "Date". I want to create a stacked bar chart showing the sum of TimeSpent for each domain on each day. As there are too many domains, I try to filter the top 10. However, that returns the top 10 overall, and I would like to show the top 10 sites per each of the days. I tried many different things, but I am struggling. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your model and connection points, and also how that initial metric "TimeSpent" was built. At first thought you could try something like the following:

`Select TimeSpent Where top (10) in (Select TimeSpent) By (connectionpoint) within (domain, ALL OTHER)`

However, you may need to incorporate a [Disconnected Date Dimension](https://help.gooddata.com/doc/enterprise/en/data-integration/data-modeling-in-gooddata/data-modeling-using-the-cloudconnect-tool/data-modeling-tutorials-for-cloudconnect-and-apis/painless-disconnected-date-dimensions) into the LDM in order to make this work in your use case.